# Can a discrete function converge to a continous function?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, approximation

Let $f\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$, let also $X \subset [a,b] = \left\{x_0,\ldots,x_k \right\}, Y = \left\{ f(x_0),\ldots, f(x_k) \right\}$. I guess that if I let $k\rightarrow  \infty$ then some how I should be able to retrieve $f$ Is it possible to prove that? or the only way is to build an approximation by such samples an d then prove that such approximation converges?

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike in finite dimention spaces, there are many different definitions of convergence in $C^{\infty}[a,b]$. Besides, you don't seem aware of it, but $\mathbb{N} $ and $\mathbb{R} $ have very different cardinals. You may want to check out some definitions of convergence and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I think you actually answered me... (with the cardinality argument).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, and thus in particular uniformly continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, then making successively tighter approximations (e.g. by linear interpolation) should give you functions that get closer and closer to $f$, and thus you are able to "retrieve" it. Note, that it is not sufficient that $k \to \infty$, you actually need that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\max_{0 \leq i < k} |x_i - x_{i+1}| = 0.
$$
Otherwise you could pick all points $x_i$ in, say, $[\frac{a+b}2,b]$, and never properly approximate $f$ on the first half of the interval.

Comment: So in your argument your saying that if I build an approximation with piecewise linear interpolation then I will have convergence, right? Is there no way to state that a discrete set could converge to a continuous one? because of the cardinality argumento provided by @Vincent?

Comment: I don't know what it would mean for a discrete *set* to converge to a continuous one. My answer is the following: if you have a continuous function on a closed interval, then you can approximate it arbitrarily well, using only a finite amount of information per approximation (namely, some function values). Of course, you might need more and more information for better approximations. 

Regarding his comment about various types of convergence: this works for the uniform norm, which is the strongest form of convergence typically considered on the space $C^\infty[a,b]$, I'm pretty sure.